# append not worked in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in JavaScript. I'm using the following code in a js file that by Ajax Upload picture and in onComplete function using the following code to perview image and worked good in chrome and Firefox.In IE it's not working. how can I solve this problem

```
$('<div class="upLoadedHolder" >'+'<img class="ImgPreviwe" width="100"  height="100"/>'+
'<span class="delete">'+'delete'+'</span>'+'</div>').appendTo(document.getElementById("slider"));

$('<div class="UploadInfo">  نام فایل :<span class="fileName">' +
fileName + '</span>حجم عکس :<span class="fileSize">' + fileSize +
'</span><a href="#">حذف</a></div>').appendTo(document.getElementsByClassName("qq-upload-drop-area"));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but as a general tip if you're using jQuery `.appendTo("#slider")` will get you the same result as `.appendTo(document.getElementById("slider"))`, and similarly you can use `.appendTo(".qq-upload-drop-area")` to append to elements with that class.

Comment: If you are using jQuery 2.0+ and want to get it run for IE8 then I recommanded you to use jQuery 1.10.x which work fine with IE8-.

Answer (score 1):

More jQuery helps with browser compatibility:

```
$('#slider').append('<div class="upLoadedHolder" >'+'<img class="ImgPreviwe" width="100"
height="100"/>'+'<span
class="delete">'+'delete'+'</span>'+'</div>');

$('.qq-upload-drop-area').append('<div class="UploadInfo">  نام فایل :<span class="fileName">' +
fileName + '</span>حجم عکس :<span class="fileSize">' + fileSize +
'</span><a
href="#">حذف</a></div>');
```

Comment: Careful with the first #slider append which might be not the correct appending contents.